# RxJS combineLatest operator weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, rx-java, rxjs5

I have a query regarding RxJS combineLatest operator. I have modified the example given in

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

as follows:

```
//timerOne emits first value at 1s, then once every 4s
const timerOne = Rx.Observable.timer(1000, 4000);
//timerTwo emits first value at 2s, then once every 4s
const timerTwo = Rx.Observable.timer(2000, 4000)
//timerThree emits first value at 3s, then once every 4s
const timerThree = Rx.Observable.of(false);

//when one timer emits, emit the latest values from each timer as an array
const combined = Rx.Observable
.combineLatest(
    timerOne,
    timerTwo,
    timerThree
);

const subscribe = combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    //grab latest emitted values for timers one, two, and three
    const [timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree] = latestValues;


  if(latestValues[0] === 3) {    
    this.timerThree = Rx.Observable.of(true);
  }

  console.log(
    `Timer One Latest: ${timerValOne}, 
     Timer Two Latest: ${timerValTwo}, 
     Timer Three Latest: ${timerValThree}`
   );
});
```

I expect the value of timerThree to change to **true** bit it always keep on printing **false** as shown in the output snippet:

```
"Timer One Latest: 3, 
 Timer Two Latest: 2, 
 Timer Three Latest: false"
"Timer One Latest: 3, 
 Timer Two Latest: 3, 
 Timer Three Latest: false"
"Timer One Latest: 4, 
 Timer Two Latest: 3, 
 Timer Three Latest: false"
```

Any idea why this is happening? Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to be aware of here is that `timerThree` isn't an observable in itself, but rather a reference to an observable object.  When you use `combineLatest`, it is combining that object, not the variable that's referencing it.  So when you assign `timerThree` to a new observable, it's now pointing to a new object, but `combined` is still using the old one.

If you want to be able to change the value of `timerThree`, try using a `Subject` instead.  Then you can push new values to it with `timerThree.next`.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing on John's answer:

`this.timerThree` is undefined at the moment of `latestValues[0] === 3` because when inside a lambda function the `this` refers to the 'nearest outer scope.

If you were to run this in the browser the `this` would be the `window` object and so you are merely adding a property to the window object.

Also `timerThree` is defined as `const` meaning that it will throw an error if you try a reassignment on the same object (but you're assigning to a different object as explained above.

Playing around with fiddle I got something that does what you want although this needs work to remove code duplication:

```
//timerOne emits first value at 1s, then once every 4s
const timerOne = Rx.Observable.timer(1000, 4000);
//timerTwo emits first value at 2s, then once every 4s
const timerTwo = Rx.Observable.timer(2000, 4000)
//timerThree emits first value at 3s, then once every 4s
let timerThree = Rx.Observable.timer(3000, 4000)

//when one timer emits, emit the latest values from each timer as an array
let combined = Rx.Observable
.combineLatest(
    timerOne,
    timerTwo,
    timerThree
);

const subscribe = combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    //grab latest emitted values for timers one, two, and three
    const [timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree] = latestValues;

  if(latestValues[0] === 3) {
    console.log("this ===>", this);
    console.log("this.timerThree ===> ", this.timerThree);
    subscribe.unsubscribe();
    combined = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(timerOne, timerTwo, Rx.Observable.of(true));
    combined.subscribe(lvs => {
        const [tv1, tv2, tv3] = lvs
      console.log(
        `Timer One Latest: ${tv1}, 
         Timer Two Latest: ${tv2}, 
         Timer Three Latest: ${tv3}`
       );
    })
  }
  console.log(
    `Timer One Latest: ${timerValOne}, 
     Timer Two Latest: ${timerValTwo}, 
     Timer Three Latest: ${timerValThree}`
   );
});
```

Notice the `unsubscribe()` call to prevent the previously combined timers from executing again, the new call to `combineLatest` and the new `Observable` to print `true`.

I also had to change `timerThree` from `const` to `let` to be able to reassign it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mygy9j86/30/)